# Get fragments of URI in Vapor

Tags: swift, vapor

For my Vapor application, I need to read the fragment of a request's URI.

```swift
let drop = Droplet()

drop.get("fragment") {
    request in

    print("URI: \(request.uri)")
    print("Fragment: \(request.uri.fragment)")

    return ""
}
```

The problem is: When I request `http://myserver/fragment#hello`, the `request.uri.fragment` is `nil`. This is printed in the console:

```
URI: http://localhost:8080/fragment
Fragment: nil
```

Am I missing something? The [Vapor documentation](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/http/request.html) does not mention any case, where the fragment is not included in the `URI`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URI fragments are only for the client. Your Vapor server doesn't even receive them. If you want to send the data in the fragment to your server, you should either use query parameters directly, or you'll need to parse the fragment in the client (i.e. JavaScript if this is a web app) and pass them to the server some other way.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier):

> Fragments depend on the document MIME type and are evaluated by the client (Web browser). Clients are not supposed to send URI-fragments to servers when they retrieve a document

Comment: Hi, I couldn't understand your answer fully. If I am using Postman as my client talking to my Vapor server, what should I do to get a non nil ``Fragment``? I also did read the Vapor documentation pointed by the OP. I also had a test like what the OP did.

Comment: Postman won't send the fragment to the server, the fragment is only for the client (web browser usually). What is in the fragment that you want to access on the server?

Comment: Hey thanks! But it's the same. If I visit the route I put into my Vapor codes using a browser, Vapor still gets a ``nil`` Fragment. What's in the fragment that I want to access? Really, nothing. I'm just curious, and perhaps I will need this ``fragment`` thing in the future. +1 to your answer.

Comment: The browser never sends the fragment to the server. Vapor will **always** get a `nil` fragment. The fragment identifier is only meant for the browser itself to use. Here's some more information since you're curious: https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/